# xhtml2pdf - loading static CSS files and images in Django

Tags: python, django, xhtml2pdf

How do I use xhtml2pdf in Django to create a PDF document from an HTML file, using my css stylesheet and bootstrap styles?

The xhtml2pdf docs describe adding stylesheets / images via a link_callback function.

I tried the below:

1: I copied the "Using xhtml2pdf in Django" code from the docs into my project:
https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#using-xhtml2pdf-in-django

2: Created an html template. In the html template, I use `{% load static %}` tag along with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'subs_app/css/main.min.css' %}">`

I get the following error:

> SuspiciousFileOperation at /invoice/pdf/1 The joined path
> (C:\static\subs_app\css\main.min.css) is located outside of the base
> path component (C:\Users\office\dev\subs\subs_project\static)

3: I also tried ditching the `{% load static %}` method and linking to the stylesheet directly via the relative path, but this doesn't work either.

Comment: hey, did you able to resolve this issue? I do have a same issue with static files in xhtml2pdf

Answer (score 0):

I've had a simuliar problem with when using the example as described in the documentation of xthml2pdf. Then I've found [this issue](https://github.com/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf/issues/548) and spotted, that the author didn't use the static finders of Django as it is in the example code. So I've also removed the finders and changed the `link_callback` function to this:

```py
def link_callback(uri, rel):
    """
    Convert HTML URIs to absolute system paths so xhtml2pdf can access those
    resources
    """
    import os
    from django.conf import settings

    static_url = settings.STATIC_URL       # Typically /static/
    static_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT     # Typically /home/userX/project_static/
    media_url = settings.MEDIA_URL         # Typically /media/
    media_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT       # Typically /home/userX/project_static/media/
    base_dir = settings.BASE_DIR           # Project's base directory

    if uri.startswith(media_url):
        path = os.path.join(media_root, uri.replace(media_url, ""))
    elif uri.startswith(static_url):
        path = os.path.join(static_root, uri.replace(static_url, ""))
    else:
        return os.path.join(base_dir, '../', uri)

    # make sure that file exists
    if not os.path.isfile(path):
        raise Exception(
            'media URI must start with %s or %s' % (static_url, media_url)
        )
    return path
```

Currently I still have problems with the layout, but at least the CSS is found with the `SuspiciousFileOperation` error.